# Como criar um coluna apenas em uma linha de uma tabela HTML?

Tags: html5

Gostaria de saber se teria a possibilidade de dentro de uma mesma linha contida dentro de uma tabela <kbd>HTML</kbd>, e apenas nesta `linha`, ter outra `coluna`. Para ilustrar o que preciso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem observar na última linha gostaria de criar mais uma nova coluna. Já pesquisei muito, mas não consegui encontrar uma solução para o que necessito. Até o momento estou posicionando o conteúdo da segunda coluna com um pipe apenas, gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de ser feito com as tags HTML da tabela:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Operador</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>863599408</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>821314336</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>874939413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>892363568</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>889911348</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>100180001</span> 
        | VISÃO:<span>000006015</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar mais um `<td>` na última linha e colocar o atributo `colspan="2"` nas colunas que ocuparão 2 espaços:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Operador</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">863599408</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">821314336</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">874939413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">892363568</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">889911348</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>100180001</span> 
      </td>
      <td>
        VISÃO:<span>000006015</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Valeu, obrigado!